# How can I rewrite this as a select statement using group by instead of using a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am revisiting some old code I wrote for a report when I was still very new to SQL (MSSQL). It does what it is supposed to but its not the prettiest or most efficient.

The dummy code below mimics what I currently have in place. Here I am trying to get counts for the number of contracts that are open over the last 5 weeks. For this example a contract is considered open if the start date of the contract happens before of during the given week and the end date happens during or after the given week.

dbo.GetWeekStart(@Date DATETIME, @NumOfWeeks INT, @FirstDayOfWeek CHAR(3)) is a function that will return the first day of each week based on the date provided for a specified number of weeks. ie SELECT * FROM dbo.GetWeekStart('20120719', -2, 'MON') will return the 2 mondays prior to July 19, 2012.

How can I simplify this? I think there is someone to do this without a loop but I have not been able to figure it out.

```
DECLARE @RunDate DATETIME,
    @Index INT,
    @RowCount INT,
    @WeekStart DATETIME,
    @WeekEnd DATETIME

DECLARE @Weeks TABLE
(
    WeekNum INT IDENTITY(0,1),
    WeekStart DATETIME,
    WeekEnd DATETIME
)

DECLARE @Output TABLE
(
    WeekStart DATETIME,
    OpenContractCount INT
)

SET @RunDate = GETDATE()

INSERT INTO @Weeks (WeekStart, WeekEnd)
SELECT WeekStart,
DATEADD(ss,-1,DATEADD(ww,1,WeekStart))
FROM dbo.[GetWeekStart](@RunDate, -5, 'MON') 

SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Weeks)
SET @Index = 0

WHILE @Index < @RowCount
BEGIN
    SET @WeekStart = (SELECT WeekStart FROM @Weeks WHERE WeekNum = @Idx)
    SET @WeekEnd = (SELECT WeekEnd FROM @Weeks WHERE WeekNum = @Idx)

    INSERT INTO @Output (WeekStart, OpenContractCount)
    SELECT @WeekStart,
    COUNT(*)
    FROM Contracts c
    WHERE c.StartDate <= @WeekEnd
    AND ISNULL(c.EndDate, GETDATE()) >= @WeekStart

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END
SELECT * FROM @Output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why this wouldn't work:

```
DECLARE @RunDate DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT  WeekStart, COUNT(*)
FROM    Contracts c
        INNER JOIN dbo.[GetWeekStart](@RunDate, -5, 'MON') 
            ON c.StartDate < DATEADD(WEEK, 1, WeekStart)
            AND (c.EndDate IS NULL OR c.EndDate >= @WeekStart)
GROUP BY WeekStart
```

I am not sure how you are generating your dates within your function, just in case you are using a loop/recursive CTE I'll include a query that doesn't use loops/cursors etc.

```
DECLARE @RunDate DATETIME = GETDATE()

-- SET DATEFIRST AS 1 TO ENSURE MONDAY IS THE FIRST DAY OF THE WEEK
-- CHANGE THIS TO SIMULATE CHANGING YOUR WEEKDAY INPUT TO db
SET DATEFIRST 1 

-- SET RUN DATE TO BE THE START OF THE WEEK
SET @RunDate = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @RunDate), @RunDate) AS DATE)

;WITH Weeks AS
(   SELECT  TOP 5 -- CHANGE THIS TO CHANGE THE WEEKS TO RUN
            DATEADD(WEEK, 1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Object_ID), @RunDate) [WeekStart]
    FROM    sys.All_Objects
)
SELECT  WeekStart, COUNT(*)
FROM    Contracts c
        INNER JOIN Weeks
            ON c.StartDate < DATEADD(WEEK, 1, WeekStart)
            AND (c.EndDate IS NULL OR c.EndDate >= @WeekStart)
GROUP BY WeekStart
```

Comment: I took a little while to get back to this, but this solution worked out well for me and offered a performance improvement over my original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did this quick but it should work

```
/*CTE generates Start & End Dates for 5 weeks
Start Date = Sunday of week @ midnight
End Date = Sunday of next week @ midnight
*/
WITH    weeks
      AS ( SELECT   DATEADD(ww, -4,
                            CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() - ( DATEPART(dw,
                                                          GETDATE()) - 1 ) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)) AS StartDate
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   DATEADD(wk, 1, StartDate)
           FROM     weeks
           WHERE    DATEADD(wk, 1, StartDate) <= GETDATE()
         )
SELECT  w.StartDate ,
        COUNT(*) AS OpenContracts
FROM    dbo.Contracts c
        LEFT   JOIN weeks w ON c.StartDate < DATEADD(d, 7, w.StartDate)
                               AND ISNULL(c.EndDate, GETDATE()) >= w.StartDate
GROUP BY w.StartDate
```